# Umbraco 9 - Remove login authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 9 and I want that the Backoffice login authentication will not show up, and instead my own custom authentication for the Umbraco users will take place. I have tried using External login providers but I don't want to use Google,Facebook,etc... authentication. I want to use my own custom authentication. is it possible? thank you very much

Comment: May I ask what this custom auth is? I'd guess you could implement your own OpenID Connect client and use that... But why? :-) https://github.com/curityio/example-dotnet-openid-connect-client

Comment: The custom auth is active directory. The purpose is not to use the Umbraco authentication and then to use active directory authentication. just to use the active directory authentication. OpenID means to connect to another server? How can I define OpenID Client as active directory? Thank you:)

Comment: Umbraco 9+ uses standard ASP.NET "Core" Identity functionality (https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Security/) which supports a bunch of login providers. I would imagine it possible to find something to help you connect to an Active Directory although I haven't been able to google my way there... I haven't done anything like this with ASP.NET Core, unfortunately, so I can't really guide you further :-(

Comment: I did not succeed to create a custom login, so I am using the custom password checker, https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/security/custom-password-checker. the bad side of that is that the user login to Umbraco need to be the same as Active Directory user.